# Query returns just one record, how to get all records with multiple condition over one column?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL table:

[image]

from which I need to get all those records having role=technical Interviewer and Hr Interviewer.

The SQL query which I wrote for this is:

```
SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE role='technical Interviewer' OR 'Hr Interviewer';
```

Output:

[image]

But, the problem with this query is, it is returning just one record.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: You have a syntax error as it stands, correct the syntax and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE role IN('technical Interviewer', 'Hr Interviewer');
```

Changing to IN for role will allow you to filter for multiple items without using OR.

Comment: Thanks for the response , it worked out as expected .

Comment: No problem - if there are differences is case sensitivity you could also incorporate UPPER() or LOWER() like roksui mentioned, like so in this case - "SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE UPPER(role) IN('TECHNICAL INTERVIEWER', 'HR INTERVIEWER);" UPPER() in this case is converting all the characters in role to uppercase before evaluating them

Comment: Pretty rare that anyone runs their SQL Server is case sensitive mode...

Comment: *if there are differences is case sensitivity you could also incorporate UPPER() or LOWER()* Wrong solution. Use explicit case-independent COLLATE specifying instead.

Comment: Thanks for the details Dave - I work out of Netezza, still learning other versions of SQL, didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want find the role value is 'technical Interviewer' and 'Hr Interviewer ' you can try the fellow code

```sql
SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE role in ('technical Interviewer','Hr Interviewer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table should have data for 'Hr Interviewer'.
Your query should be as below.

```
SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE role='technical Interviewer' OR role='Hr Interviewer';
```

there is another way

```
SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE role IN ('technical Interviewer','Hr Interviewer');
```

Comment: For a better answer please point out exactly what you fixed about the first query.

Answer (score -1):

There is a syntax error in your query.

And are you sure that the name of the roles are correct? ("Hr Interviewer" -> "hr Interviewer")

One other way to write this query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM new_user WHERE LOWER(role)='technical interviewer' OR LOWER(role)='hr interviewer';
```

Also, are there are any more records that satisfy the condition?

Comment: You mean aside from the fact that there is a syntax error?

Comment: @DaleK Oops. I just noticed the syntax error in the OP's query which was the cause of the problem. The importance of reading thoroughly..

Comment: SQL comparisons by default are not case sensitive, so this change just makes the query unsargable.

Comment: @DaleK *SQL comparisons by default are not case sensitive* Where you have taken this statement from? It is obviously incorrect. Case sensitivity is defined by operands collation.

Comment: @Akina in my experience case insensitive collations are far more common then case sensitive ones. And typically people who use a case sensitive collation are very aware of it i.e. don't ask for help because of it.

Comment: @DaleK Collation is the only factor which influences the case sensitivity of the string comparing result. Test something like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8de2f2f5d0034de29d6aff2e8f86ad58 In most cases implicit value collation (specified by DB/table or connection collation) is used - which is wrong because it may confuse...